# How to 'mirror' clicks from one application to another one?

Tags: python, opencv, winapi

I am trying to capture clicks from a Windows installed application. So the goal is to get the click position with respect an opened application width and height; not the screen width and height.

For instance, say you have "Paint" open on the upper half of your screen, and you click on the "Brushes" option on the menu.

You could easily get the click position using the Python module pynput, for instance, but that will get you the position with respect the screen size. So if you have a 1920x1080 screen, the click position will be between those coordinates. However, I want the position with respect the application (Paint) size (i.e between 600 and 900; assuming Paint is opened on the left side of the screen).

It is a little hard to explain, so please take a look at the following image which should explain what I am trying to accomplish.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26DDK.png)

The image has two Paint windows. The one on the top is the window I want to track clicks from (In this case, you can't actually see the cursor but it is pointing right at the "Brushes" arrow). The second window is from OpenCV and tries to show where the click is happening (The Blue circle) but it is way off where it should actually be.

Here's an overview of my algorithm:

1. I am using win32gui to get the application's (Paint in this example) width and height. Now
   it might not be always the same application I might be using. It could be another application installed on Windows which is why I am using win32gui.
2. I then get the current mouse position (Here I am just getting the mouse position instead of the actual click position because it is easier to represent, but it is the exact same thing)
3. Finally, I grab a screenshot of the application using "mss" and pass it to OpenCV so I can draw the mouse position on it. Here's where I am getting the incorrect position.

```py
import ctypes
import win32gui
import cv2
import mss
import time
import numpy as np

## Set countdown to have enough time to put the mouse in the correct position
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)

## Get application width and height
ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware() ## No idea why but I must set this, otherwise I get wrong results from win32gui.GetWindowRect()
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Untitled - Paint")  
left, top, right, bottom = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
left = left + 8
width = right - left - 8
height = bottom - top - 8
monitor = {"top": top, "left": left, "width": width, "height": height}
print(width, height)

## Get current mouse screen position
x, y = win32gui.GetCursorPos()
print(x, y)

## Grab a screenshoot of the application
with mss.mss() as sct:
    screen = sct.grab(monitor)
img = np.array(screen)   
img = cv2.rectangle(img, (0, 0), (width, height), (255, 0, 0), 2) ## Drawing rectangle around screenshot of the application
img = cv2.circle(img, (x*width//1920, y*height//1080), 20, (255, 0, 0), -1) ## Drawing set of points from the current mouse screen position
cv2.imshow('window', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of is the coordinates of `cv2.circle` the center of the circle related to the background image(`img`).

You could use [`ScreenToClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-screentoclient) to get the converts the screen coordinates of a specified point on the screen to client-area coordinates.

```
import ctypes
import win32gui
import cv2
import mss
import time
import numpy as np

## Set countdown to have enough time to put the mouse in the correct position
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)

## Get application width and height
ctypes.windll.user32.SetProcessDPIAware() ## No idea why but I must set this, otherwise I get wrong results from win32gui.GetWindowRect()
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Untitled - Paint")  
left, top, right, bottom = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
left = left + 8
width = right - left - 8
height = bottom - top - 8
monitor = {"top": top, "left": left, "width": width, "height": height}
print(width, height)

## Get current mouse screen position
x, y = win32gui.GetCursorPos()
print(x, y)

## Grab a screenshoot of the application
with mss.mss() as sct:
    screen = sct.grab(monitor)
img = np.array(screen)   
img = cv2.rectangle(img, (0, 0), (width, height), (255, 0, 0), 2) ## Drawing rectangle around screenshot of the application
pos = win32gui.ScreenToClient(hwnd,(x,y))
x = pos[0]
y = pos[1]
print(x, y)
img = cv2.circle(img, (x, y), 20, (255, 0, 0), -1) ## Drawing set of points from the current mouse screen position
cv2.imshow('window', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:
[image]